# Why file corrupt when sending client to server through socket programming?

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to send multiple files from client to server. Files are sent successfully but problem is that when I try to open the receiving file from targetFolder it seems files are corrupted.

Why this type of problem occurring and what is the solution?
How can I solve this by modifying the code to get uncorrupted files?

**Server Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.zip.Adler32;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Checksum;

public class Server {
    public final static String dirPath = "E:\\targetFolder\\";
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(8080);
            Socket socket = servsock.accept();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

            int filesCount = dis.readInt();
            File[] files = new File[filesCount];

            for(int i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
                long fileLength = dis.readLong();
                String fileName = dis.readUTF();

                files[i] = new File(dirPath + fileName);

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(files[i]);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);


                byte[] byteArr = new byte[(int)fileLength];
                for (int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++) {
                    int b = bis.read();
                    bos.write(b);
                    byteArr[j] = (byte) b;
                }
                // CheckSum calculating
                System.out.println("============================");
                System.out.println("File Name: "+fileName);
                Checksum checksum = new Adler32();
                checksum.update(byteArr,0, byteArr.length);
                System.out.println("Check Sum: "+checksum.getValue());
                System.out.println("============================");
            }

            dis.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.zip.Adler32;
import java.util.zip.Checksum;

public class Client {
    private static String directory = "E:\\sourceFolder";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Socket sock=new Socket("localhost",8080);
            System.out.println("Connecting...");

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    sock.getOutputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

            File[] files = new File(directory).listFiles();
            dos.writeInt(files.length);

            for(File file: files) {
                long length = file.length();
                dos.writeLong(length);
                String fileName = file.getName();
                dos.writeUTF(fileName);

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                int bt = 0;
                byte[] byteArr = new byte[(int)length];

                int i = 0;
                while((bt = bis.read()) != -1) {
                    bos.write(bt);
                    byteArr[i++] = (byte) bt;
                }

                // CheckSum calculating
                System.out.println("============================");
                System.out.println("File Name: "+fileName);
                Checksum checksum = new Adler32();
                checksum.update(byteArr,0, byteArr.length);
                System.out.println("Check Sum: "+checksum.getValue());
                System.out.println("============================");
                bis.close();
            }
            dos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- "*... it seems files are corrupted.*" - How does this manifest, i.e. who did you determine that the files are corrupted?

Comment: You're losing the last chunk of every output file because you are never closing `bos` in the server. In the client you should do all the output via the `DataOutputStream`, for consistency. You don't need to collect the entire file in memory to get its checksum: see the API documentation.

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks[@user207421]

[@Turing85]Instead of further query, you should have replied by giving a solution as you understood what I actually want. My approach may not correct when asking

Comment: I will agree with @Turing85 that you should have provided more detail, but the problem was solvable by inspection so I don't agree that your 'approach when asking' was so bad.

Comment: "*you should have replied by giving a solution as you understood what I actually want*" - I highly recommend you rethink your expectations wrt. StackOverflow. We are here on our free time, without any charge. We do not **have** to provide anything.

Comment: Exactly @Turing85 It is the askers who need the answers, not the other way round. The askers therefore do not get to set the rules, and no amount of social engineering on the part of askers or indeed websites can possibly change that.

Comment: Yes, Exactly. All of you are correct. I realized that did mistake. I should remember when asking question must be explicit. Thanks.